# Examples 2-1 & 2-2 not working, Twisted O'reilly book

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to learn more about Twisted by doing examples 2-1 and 2-2 in the O'Reilly [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100322.do). The examples are for a TCP echo server & client pair.

Here's what's configured within a virtual environment:

```
Python 2.7.4
Ubuntu Release: 13.04, 64 bit
```

Using [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
$ pip freeze
Twisted==14.0.0
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Code for echoserver.py

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Code for echoclient.py

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Hello, world!")

    def dataRecieved(self, data):
        print "Server said: ", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return EchoClient()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed."
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost."
        reactor.stop()

reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

The expected output is the following:

```
$ python echoserver.py # in terminal 1
$ python echoclient.py # in terminal 2
Server said: Hello, world!
Connection lost.
```

The current output is that nothing is returned but both files start without raising errors. Please help me understand what's wrong with my configuration. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: You're going to kick yourself for this, but in `echoclient.py`, `dataRecieved` should be `dataReceived`. Just a typo.

Comment: @dano Why did you comment instead of answering?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone My understanding is that issues that turn out to be typos should be closed as off-topic. So I just put the solution in a comment and voted to close.